# How to convert image html code have animation elements to ruby image_tag

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, animation

```
<img src="assets/stockBroker_photo02.png" alt="" class="animated" data-animation="fadeInRight" data-animation-delay="300">
```

I want to convert this code to ruby on rails code meanz in image_tag. I know simple `image_tag` with class name but these data animation issue is creating. How to add these `data-animation` in `image_tag`

Answer (score 2):

Your data attributes you can write as a hash like so:

```
<%= image_tag("stockBroker_photo02.png", class: 'animated', alt: '', data: { animation: "fadeInRight", animation-delay: "300" }) %>
```

See [image_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-image_tag), there are some examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
<%= image_tag('stockBroker_photo02.png', class: 'whatever-class', data: {animation-delay: '300', animation: 'fadeInRight'} )
```

Data attributes are added as a hash at the end and are also usable in Rails `link_to` method most notably when you're looking to delete something and you add the "`data: {confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete this?"}` "

Answer (score 0):

With `image_tag` with Erb:

```
<%= image_tag filename, data: { animation: 'fadeInRight' } %>
```

With `image_tag` with HAML

```
= image_tag filename, data: { animation: 'fadeInRight' }
```

Without `image_tag` in HAML

```
%img{ src: filename, data: { animation: 'FadeInright' } }
```